# Can CruiseControl.NET Run on IIS 5.1 (WinXP Pro)?

Tags: windows-xp, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

Just wondering if anyone has successfully got ccnet 1.6.x running on an XP box (IIS 5.1). I have it installed and it builds projects (failing at the moment most likely due to file permissions), but for some reason the mapping in the web.config for showing the build XMLs via the dashboard does nothing. All I get are 404 errors. The same also goes for some projects loading of parameters, e.g. http://localhost/ccnet/server/local/project/someProject/ViewProjectParameters.aspx . Don't ask why the **"server"** is XP, but it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I figured out what the issue was. As it's IIS 5.1, I installed IIS Lockdown. I didn't realize that by default, URL paths with dots in them that aren't the file extension dot are disallowed by default. I set the `[AllowDotsInPath] = 1` in the urlscan.ini and it works like a charm now.